How to refresh Webview in Jetpack compose if url is the same?
How to refresh Webview in Jetpack compose if url is the same?
I try to use AccompanistWebViewClient
and then I try to change urlState to the same webview not reloading
How to reload the webview?
val urlState =
        rememberWebViewState()
    WebView(
        state = urlState,
        onCreated = { webView ->
            webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        },
        client = remember { webViewClient },
        chromeClient = remember { chromeViewClient }
    ) 


You need to call your WebView loading function again to load same url.

Call WebView again.
That's because instance of WebView creating new View based on URL.
https://medium.com/@kevinnzou/using-webview-in-jetpack-compose-bbf5991cfd14
